# Read Witre the same xml file using Dataset

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I have dataset reading the xml file and then write the same xml again. This process of reading and writing the xml file will work regular hits (after 10 sec). I am facing the error that the file is in process after write once from the dataset next it says an error which says

> The process cannot access the file
>   'D:\DayUsers\Official\Projects\BlocksXml\712.xml' because it is being
>   used by another process.

The error is generating when we go through the same code next time by other request.

My code is given below for the same process

```
Dataset  ds = new DataSet();
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +  "\\BlocksXml\\" + _statusDeviceID + ".xml";
System.IO.FileStream fsReadXml = new System.IO.FileStream(path,  System.IO.FileMode.Open);
ds.ReadXml(fsReadXml);
fsReadXml.Close();
// ds.ReadXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\BlocksXml\\" + _statusDeviceID + ".xml");
if (_blockData.Length.ToString() == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0] ["ArrayLength"].ToString())
{
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("ArrayLength");
    varcount = ds.Tables["Status"].Columns.Count;
    var nexcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < varcount; i++)
    {
        ds.Tables["Status"].Rows[0][i] = _blockData[i];
    }
    if (ds.Tables.Contains("tblDigitalInputRows"))
    {
        nexcount = ds.Tables["tblDigitalInputRows"].Rows.Count;
        if (nexcount > 0)
        {
            nexcount =  ds.Tables["tblDigitalInputRows"].Columns.Count;
        }
        varcount = varcount - 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < ds.Tables["tblDigitalInputRows"].Rows.Count; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nexcount - 1; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables["tblDigitalInputRows"].Rows[k][i] = _blockData[varcount];
                varcount++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (ds.Tables.Contains("tblDigitalOutputRows"))
    {
        nexcount = ds.Tables["tblDigitalOutputRows"].Rows.Count;
        if (nexcount > 0)
        {
            nexcount = ds.Tables["tblDigitalOutputRows"].Columns.Count;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < ds.Tables["tblDigitalOutputRows"].Rows.Count; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nexcount - 1; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables["tblDigitalOutputRows"].Rows[k][i] = _blockData[varcount];
                varcount++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (ds.Tables.Contains("tblAnalogInputRows"))
    {
        nexcount = ds.Tables["tblAnalogInputRows"].Rows.Count;
        if (nexcount > 0)
        {
            nexcount = ds.Tables["tblAnalogInputRows"].Columns.Count;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < ds.Tables["tblAnalogInputRows"].Rows.Count; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nexcount - 1; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables["tblAnalogInputRows"].Rows[k][i] = _blockData[varcount];
                varcount++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (ds.Tables.Contains("tblEnumInputRows"))
    {
        nexcount = ds.Tables["tblEnumInputRows"].Rows.Count;
        if (nexcount > 0)
        {
            nexcount = ds.Tables["tblEnumInputRows"].Columns.Count;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < ds.Tables["tblEnumInputRows"].Rows.Count; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nexcount - 1; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables["tblEnumInputRows"].Rows[k][i] = _blockData[varcount];
                varcount++;
            }
        }
    }

    _blockDeviceID = Convert.ToInt32(_blockData[1]);
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("ArrayLength", typeof(string));
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ArrayLength"] = _blockData.Length;
    ds.WriteXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\BlocksXml\\" + _blockData[1].ToString() + ".xml");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you doing it in multiple threads? How long this method will take to execute?

Comment: It is going to use in multiple requests. It takes few secs to get execute but after execution it still gives the same error. When we again run this , next time it reads well but gives error on writing it again. Instead FileStream  I used ds.ReadXml earlier  but the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading the XML through `FileStream` , specify the path directly in `ds.ReadXml`

```
ds.ReadXml(path);
```

Use [`DataSet.ReadXml Method (String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360dye2a.aspx)  overload which takes a file path as parameter.

*It is just my guess that the stream is not getting closed in time.*

Comment: Hi Habib, I have already done this earlier before above mentioned code, I was using simple this way you mentioned but the same problem exist. On the next request it reads well but gives error on writing the same again.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this at my end with the help of File stream. Below is the code

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        ds.ReadXml(stream);
 _blockDeviceID = Convert.ToInt32(_blockData[1]);
                            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("ArrayLength", typeof(string));
                             ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ArrayLength"] = _blockData.Length +  "";
                            // Reset the stream here to the beginning of the file!

                            ds.WriteXml(stream);
}
```